# Exported jar finds some files (not all) even though the paths are the same

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When I run my program from eclipse, it shows up fine, the images from Resources\ show up, as do the sounds from the same place, and the text files are found properly. However, when I export my jar, and copy the resources into it with 7Zip, the images will work, but the sounds and the text files can't be found, even though they're in the same folder, with the same path used to find them in my code. I can fix this by putting a folder next to the jar file named Resources, and put everything in there, but I'd like to know why just putting it in the jar file only worked for the images, and how I can get it to work with the text and audio files as well.
An example to show you what I mean:

```
File inventory = new File("Resources/inv.txt");
threadpath = "Resources/threads.wav";
enemy1 = new Sprite(new Texture("Resources/miniForestGolem.png"));
```

When I run it in eclipse, all three work fine, but when I export it, and put the resources folder in the jar file, only the image works.

**Edit:**

I know how to include my resources, and have done so, I'm asking about *how/why some of the resources aren't able to be accessed*, even after adding them in.

Comment: Please show us the code you use to retrieve the resources.  Are you using YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() in order to retrieve them?

Comment: File inventory = new File("Resources/inv.txt"); for the text file

Comment: threadpath = "Resources/threads.wav";threadpath = "Resources/threads.wav"; for the wav file

Comment: and enemy1 = new Sprite(new Texture("Resources/miniForestGolem.png")); for the png

Comment: Please add the code you put in the comments as an edit to the question (instead of the example that won't compile). May be useful to include you folder hierarchy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from your comments we can infer the difference between executing it from eclipse and executing it from a .jar.

- From eclipse: it works, because all that `new File(...)` find an actual file in Resources/
- From the .jar: it won't work, since there is no file in a relative ./Resources/ path from the execution path of the application.

The way to make it work is the next:

- Make sure Eclipse recognizes Resources/ as a source folder (right-click on project properties, Java Build Path, and add it as a source path)
- Look for a replacement for your API methods that, instead of `File` objects, use `InputStreams`.  Once you have it, retrieve all your resources as InputStreams taken from the classpath.  If you are inside MyClass.java, do this: `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Resources/inv.txt")`, etc.

What you have achieved by doing this: instead of `File` objects built on actual operating system files, you will be retrieving `InputStreams` read straight from your java application classpath.  This way, you can package them into a jar, or into a WEB-INF/classes directory inside a web application, or a library folder in some application servers... wherever you like as long as it is into the application classpath.  I would do this if I had to package your application in a portable and usable way.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working, now how would I go about writing to a file such as Resources/inv.txt?

Comment: Now that's a different problem.  With the solution I just gave you, there is no way that you open, edit and save again that particular file.  In that case, you should provide the file separately and perhaps show a `JFileChooser` or something similar for the user to be able to select an existing inv.txt in their hard disk